# Find the file having lowest timestamp

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement which needs to be done by only using Java Script and would appreciate if someone can help here.

1. We have 10 files coming into a folder of format MMddyyyyHHmmss (ex. 07192013114030) - MonthDayYearHourMinuteSecond
2. The file gets dropped from an external system once every day
3. When the 11th file comes in I need to find the file that was dropped on the first and delete it so that the total count of the files should always be 10 (latest 10 files)

Sample example

```
07192013114030
07202013114030
07212013114030
07222013114030
07232013114030
07242013114030
07252013114030
07262013114030
07272013114030
07282013114030
```

When the 11th file comes in on `07292013114030`, I want to find the file `07192013114030` using Java Script.

I can provide the incoming file names in any format, ex. `MM/dd/yyyy/HHmmss` or `MM_dd_yyyy_HH_mm_ss` if that helps to do this using JS

Comment: This is a job for server-side code, not JS.

Comment: ISO date format, or die!

Comment: This is the horrific date format I've yet seen

Comment: When you say `Java Script` do you mean 'Java' or 'JavaScript'? This can be done in Java but not JavaScript unless you are using JavaScript on the server-side with Node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can get the dates in any format, get them in `YYYYMMDDHHmmss` format. Then get those timestamps in an array. There's not enough information about your system in your question to explain how to do this but just loop through the files pulling out the timestamps and pushing them into an array.

Basically you should have an array like this when you're done:

```
dates = ['20130719114030',
         '20130720114030',
         '20130721114030',
         '20130722114030',
         '20130723114030',
         '20130724114030',
         '20130725114030',
         '20130726114030',
         '20130727114030',
         '20130728114030'];
```

Once done, simply sort the array:

```
dates.sort();
```

Dates will be in alphanumeric order, which also happens to be chronological order because of our date format. The oldest date will be the first one in the array, so

```
dates[0] // '20130719114030'
```

Again, there's not enough information about your system to explain how to delete the file, but perhaps you could loop through the files again to find a matching timestamp, then delete the file.

Comment: Thanks Travis, this may work out.  I'll take care of the deletion part as long I can find the oldest date.  Let me give a try.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced with Javascript, but my logical progression would be:

Out of the 11 files, find the lowest year
If the same
Out of the 11 files, find the lowest month
[...]
all the way down to second

Answer (score 0):

Convert them all to date objects and then compare them. You would only have to do two pass throughs of the list to find the smallest date (one to convert and one to compare)... instead of extracting each snippet and going through the list multiple times.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp